# Absolute Position Or Absolute Padding

Tags: html, css

**UPDATED**

I know padding make distance from border but

**Why we must use padding for absolute position ?**

I have this :

```
         #Menu ul li a{width:126px;
                       height:20px;
                       text-align:center;
                       color:Black;
                       position:absolute;
                       text-decoration:none;
                       background-color:inherit;
                       padding:15px 0 15px 0;}
```

But why I should set padding-top and padding-bottom too? ( if don't ,height won't be set to 20.)

will padding  be set form it's parent coord or the coordinates of browser(document)?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding applies the measurement to the inside of the element. It's often desired to not have text or other elements at the very edge of a block element. Padding is often **not** about positioning, it's about **aesthetics**.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Padding is nowhere near the same as positioning. There is no such thing as "absolute padding". And Absolute positioning is entirely different than padding. Positioning controles where an element is located X/Y. Padding controls how items within that element interact with the edges of the element.

Comment: I have trace many of menus that they have abs position and padding too and if I remove padding from that , the menu will collapse.

Comment: Again.. padding is about aesthetics. Most often designers don't want text butting right against the edge of an element. Padding is not about positioning, it's about look and feel. Adding padding to an element changes the element's size. In that sense, if there is positioning, the padded size must be used for any positioning. No one is REQUIRED to use padding. However, things often look better if there's a bit of space between elements.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to separate the content of the element from the border (or the edge of the background).

Comment: why we should use padding for absolute position ?

Comment: I might have had a little more port tonight than I should have, but I'm pretty sure we aren't playing "Jeopardy!, America's Favorite Quiz Show®"

Answer (score 0):

I think Scott's comments have answered your question. In answer to your 2nd question, maybe there's another selector within your code affecting the height of the anchor as the code works with or without the padding-top/bottom.

With height: 20px you're creating a block of 20px in height, then providing the combination of margins do not exceed 20px, the text of the anchor is positioned within this 'block' using the padding.